# Select Query Joining 3 Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, join

I've 3 Tables

**Personel** : id, name
**Department** : id, name
**Match_Dept_Per** : dept_id, pers_id, workInfo

**Foreign Keys :** 
dept_id --> Department.id
pers_id --> Personel.id

**Example Data :**
**Personel :**
1, Emir Civas
2, Sercan Tuncay

**Department :**
1, Sales
2, Planning

**Match_Dept_Per :**
1,1,Manager

What I'm trying to do is, listing peoples names, their department names and workInfos like:

```
ID | Pers. Name | Dept Name | Work Info
---------------------------------------
1  | Emir Civas | Sales     | Manager
```

I can do this with a simple select query:

```
select p.id, p.name, d.name, m.workInfo
  from personel p, department d, match_dept_per m
 where p.id = m.pers_id and d.id = m.dept_id;
```

Here is [sample fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d65b/5) of my schema and this query.

However what I need is to display other persons that their id's are not inserted to match_dept_per table. And Set "Unknown" As the Null Values. Like:

```
ID | Pers. Name    | Dept Name | Work Info
------------------------------------------
1  | Emir Civas    | Sales     | Manager
2  | Sercan Tuncay | Unknown   | Unknown
```

Since I'm Using Match_Dept_Per Table, If Personel ID isn't Added, I can't do anything.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I believe you will need to incorporate the ISNULL() function as part of your SQL statement. ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value ) so this will allow you to replace the value checked if null with UNKNOWN. I won't post an answer because I don't have the time to rewrite your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `left outer join` to include all persons even if they are not associated with the other tables:

```
select p.id,
       p.name,
       ifnull(d.name, 'Unknown') DepName,
       ifnull(m.workInfo, 'Unknown') workInfo
  from personel p
       left outer join match_dept_per m
           on p.id = m.pers_id
       left outer join department d
           on d.id = m.dept_id
```

Here is a [demo fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d65b/9).

As you seem to use MS SQL, you might need to use `isnull()` instead of `ifnull()`. But I would ommit that anyway because I think it's better to have a `NULL` in the code where you use the data (Java, C#, whatever). You can control the output there.

Comment: to complete this answer, add ifnull() for the fields from department and match_dept_per.